# How to exclude groups with incomplete data in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have combined numerical data from multiple trials and I want to look only at groups with complete data across all trials in ggplot. My numerical data is cd and groups are did:

```
+-------+-----+-------+
| trial | did |  cd   |
+-------+-----+-------+
|     1 |   1 | 12.07 |
|     2 |   1 | 16.8  |
|     3 |   1 | 11.83 |
|     1 |   2 | 13.43 |
|     2 |   2 | 12.54 |
|     1 |   3 | 8.3   |
|     1 |   4 | 6.39  |
|     2 |   4 | 5.6   |
|     3 |   4 | 6.46  |
|     1 |   5 | 11.63 |
|     1 |   6 | 7.77  |
|     2 |   6 | 10.87 |
|     3 |   6 | 12.15 |
|     2 |   7 | 24.23 |
|     3 |   7 | 7.72  |
|     1 |   8 | 8.71  |
+-------+-----+-------+
```

here is my code for making a chart:

```
f <- ggplot(data, aes(x = trial, y = cd, group = did))

f  + geom_line(aes(color=did,group=did), show.legend = F)
```

I want to exclude did's with missing trial data.

[click here to see my plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSjb0.jpg)

Comment: `ggplot` is a plotting library. This is more of a data manipulation problem, so I think it would make sense to exclude these groups before plotting. Also, it's much more helpful if you provide a minimal example. As an example, we could help you more if you posted data on only a few groups where some would be ones you want to exclude.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Hopefully the changes I made to my question help to clarify. Please let me know if this needs further clarification. As you can tell, I am fairly new here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @Mike H, a better way to do this is to first subset to complete groups. One way is to `filter` using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data %>%
  group_by(did) %>%
  filter(n()==3) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = trial, y = cd, group = did)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color=did,group=did), show.legend = F)
```

[image]

**Data:**

```
data = structure(list(trial = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 
3, 2, 3, 1), did = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 
7, 8), cd = c(12.07, 16.8, 11.83, 13.43, 12.54, 8.3, 6.39, 5.6, 
6.46, 11.63, 7.77, 10.87, 12.15, 24.23, 7.72, 8.71)), .Names = c("trial", 
"did", "cd"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```